# Получить data атрибут у последнего select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите разобраться.

У меня есть форма с несколькими списками. Нужно получить `data` атрибут последнего `select` в `div`.

Пробовал вот так, но не работает.

```
$("#form-ingredient select:last-child").data('id')
```

Но если поставить вместо `select input`, тогда всё работает.

```
<div id="form-ingredient">
                    <select id="ingredient-1" class="form-control" data-id="1">
                        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                        <option value="Колбаса">Колбаса</option>
                        <option value="Огурцы">Огурцы</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

<select id="ingredient-2" class="form-control" data-id="2">
                        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                        <option value="Колбаса">Колбаса</option>
                        <option value="Огурцы">Огурцы</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: разметочку то покажите примерную

Comment: Смотрите, исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз ваш селект добавляется динамически, то его нужно найти:

```
$('.parent').find('select');
```

А ещё советую "выбирать" элементы через [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), вот пример:

```js
let data = $('.selects').find('select').eq(-1).data('id');
  console.info(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selects">
  <select data-id="1"></select>
  <select data-id="22"></select>
  <select data-id="333"></select>
  <select data-id="4444"></select>
  <select data-id="55555"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне не option у селекта нужно, а data атрибут.

И id у select формируются динамически. Я не могу заранее знать какой id.

Вот и стоит задача, чтобы в div с id form-ingredient найти последний select  и взять у него нужный атрибут.

Comment: @Сергей, вы демо посмотрите, там у последнего option берётся data атрибут.

Comment: Почти, только без option.
Я решил проблему. Ниже ответ

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log( $("#test_div select:last-child").data('id') ); // берём внутри div последний селект
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_div">
  <select id="test_select" data-id="1">
    <option>1 option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно получить именно у последнего select, нельзя привязываться к id
Select добавляются динамически.

Comment: console.log( $("select:last-child").data('id') ); // берём внутри последний селект и у него аттрибут

Приложите текст html кода, чтобы я мог более точно ответить

Comment: Я также делал. $("#form-ingredient select:last-child").data('id')
Не работает. Пишет undefined

Comment: $("#form-ingredient select') - что выдаёт?

Comment: Если прописать так, тогда выдаёт информацию о select

Comment: $("#form-ingredient select").data('id') - а так?

Comment: Показывает значение атрибута data, но только для первого select

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, я его изменил, чтобы наглядно было

Comment: Да, так работает.

Но как взять select внутри определённого div ?

Comment: @Сергей, `$('определённый-див select')`

Comment: $("#form-ingredient select").data('id')

прописывал так. Берёт у первого

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно:

```js
let select = [...document.querySelectorAll("#form-ingredient select")].pop();
let data = select && select.getAttribute("data-id");
console.log(data)
```

```html
<div id="form-ingredient">
  <select id="ingredient-1" class="form-control" data-id="1"></select>
  <select id="ingredient-2" class="form-control" data-id="2"></select>
</div>
```

Или так:

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll("#form-ingredient select");
let lastData = selects.length && selects[selects.length - 1].getAttribute("data-id") || undefined
console.log(lastData)
```

```html
<div id="form-ingredient">
  <select id="ingredient-1" class="form-control" data-id="1"></select>
  <select id="ingredient-2" class="form-control" data-id="2"></select>
</div>
```

ps: в тегах есть `javascript` по этому без жуквери

Comment: мне понравился второй  ответ с использованием `spread` оператора :)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось. Спасибо. Ниже код с решением.

```
<div id="form-ingredient">
<select id="ingredient-1" class="form-control" data-id="1">
                    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                    <option value="Колбаса">Колбаса</option>
                    <option value="Огурцы">Огурцы</option>
                </select>

                <select id="ingredient-2" class="form-control" data-id="2">
                    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
                    <option value="Колбаса">Колбаса</option>
                    <option value="Огурцы">Огурцы</option>
                </select>
</div>



$("#form-ingredient select").eq(-1).data('id')
```